# How to use CIDEr metric

Tags: deep-learning, metrics

I see that CIDEr is a universal metric in Image Captioning.

I want to use this metric on my project, but I can't find any library. There is few info. CIDEr can only be seen in paper. And I can have searched just BLUE library which is used to evaluate NLP.

Anybody knows how to use this metric?

If there is no way, how can I evaluate my image-captioning model?

p.s. I use OFA model on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/tylin/coco-caption

Here is the github link which can be the answer. I can use how to apply CIDEr metric on my project by referring this repository.